# Return the read cursor to the start of the file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read into two file (name,number) at the same time and get value of each possible pair.
The two file are like this:

```
*name1   
John            
*name2                      
Paul
```

```
*number1        
25        
*number2         
45
```

What i'm trying to obtain are label and result like:

```
*name1 *number1 John 25
*name2 *number2 John 45
*name2 *number1 Paul 25
*name2 *number2 Paul 45
```

Since i come from python i've tried to do it with two loop like this:

```sh
name=/home/davide/name.txt
number=/home/davide/number.txt
while read name; do
    if [[ ${name:0:1} == "*" ]]; then
        n=$(echo $name)
    else
        while read number; do
                if [[ ${number:0:1} == "*" ]]; then
                    echo $number $n
                else
                    echo $name $number 
                fi
        done < $number
    fi
done < $name
```

I have the first two pair so my guess it's that i need a command to start from the beginning of number again (like seek(0) on python) but i haven't found a similar one for bash.
I also get an "ambiguous redirect" error and i don't understand why.

Comment: To be clear, you just want to read the 2 files in parallel? You are not looking for matching lines? Your code loops through the inner file many times per loop through the outer file, and it is not clear that it does what you want at all. You might want to start by calling `column` to merge the two files into two columns in a single file?

Comment: See how you're using `name` and `number` both to refer to filenames and to refer to values from those files? Make the former something like `number_file` and `name_file` and that problem goes away. And making it `< "$number"` and `< "$name"` **with the quotes** will avoid the "ambiguous redirect" errors, giving you better messages when the value doesn't expand to a valid filename.

Comment: ...running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds (which will include quoting errors) is always a good step to take **before** asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: BTW, `n=$(echo $name)` is both slow and buggy compared to `n=$name`. (To understand the "slow", keep in mind that `$( )` forks a copy of the shell as a separate process; to understand the "buggy", see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: `< "$number"`, if `number` still had your filename, *does* reopen the file and start from the very beginning. (It doesn't `seek()`, so you pay the performance cost of `open()`ing twice). Problem is that you overwrote the variable with a different value, so the filename is no longer in it.

Comment: BTW, consider `[[ $number = '*'* ]]` as a terser way to check whether the leading character in a string is a `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up your input files:

```
printf >name.txt '%s\n' '*name1' John '*name2' Paul                      
printf >number.txt '%s\n' '*number1' 25 '*number2' 45
```

...the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
name_file=name.txt
number_file=number.txt

while IFS= read -r name1 && IFS= read -r value1; do
  while IFS= read -r name2 && IFS= read -r value2; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name1 $name2 $value1 $value2"
  done <"$number_file"
done <"$name_file"
```

...properly outputs:

```
*name1 *number1 John 25
*name1 *number2 John 45
*name2 *number1 Paul 25
*name2 *number2 Paul 45
```

---

What changed?

- We stopped using `name` and `number` both for the filenames and for the values read from them. Because of this, when you ran `<$number`, it no longer had the filename `number.txt` in it after the first iteration; likewise for `$name`.
- We started quoting all expansions (`"$foo"`, not `$foo`). See the http://shellcheck.net/ warning [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086), and [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), explaining why even `echo $foo` is buggy.
- Running `read` with the `-r` argument and `IFS` set to an empty value prevents it from consuming literal backslashes or pruning leading and trailing newlines.
- Using two `read`s inside the condition of each `while` loop lets us read two lines at a time from each file (as is appropriate, given the intent to process content in pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Bash operates more easly on "streams", not like, on the data itself.

- first substitute every second newline starting from the first for a tabulation or a space or other separator
- then "paste" the files together
- Then rearange columns, from `*name1 John *number1 25` to `*name1 *number1 John 25`

```
cat >name.txt <<EOF
*name1
John
*name2
Paul
EOF

cat <<EOF >number.txt
*number1
25
*number2
45
EOF

paste <(<name.txt sed 'N;s/\n/\t/') <(<number.txt sed 'N;s/\n/\t/') |
awk '{print $1,$3,$2,$4}'
```

will output:

```
*name1 *number1 John 25
*name2 *number2 Paul 45
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you use the variable `name` for both the file path and the while-loop variable.  This causes the "ambiguous redirect" error. Two lines need fix e.g.:

```
name_file=/home/davide/name.txt
done < $name_file
```

No need to for seek(0) in shell scripts. Just process the file again, e.g:

```
while read line ; do
    echo "== $line =="
done < /some/file

while read line ; do
    echo "--> ${line:0:1}"
done < /some/file
```

This is less efficient and less flexible than a more real programming language where you can `seek()`.  But that's about differences, advantages and disadvantages between shell scripting and programming.

By the way, this line:

```
n=$(echo $name)
```

... is merely a awkward way of just doing:

```
n=$name
```

This can cause your script to behave quite unpredictable when `$name` contains special character like `*`. And since `$name` is read from a text file, this not unlikely to happen. (thanks Charles Duffy for making this point)

Comment: If you're going to showcase good practices, best to fix the quoting as well. And to *really* do it right, run the `read`s in a mode where they don't trim leading and trailing whitespace or munge backslashes.

Comment: BTW, I disagree that `n=$(echo $name)` is "harmless" except for CPU impact. If `name='*'`, then `n=$(echo $name)` will put a list of filenames in `n`, whereas `n=$name` copies the existing contents exactly.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Yes, makes sense. Particularly you point about `n=$(echo $anme)`. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your example you overwrite the variable `$number`. So you have issues on reading file `$number` beginning from the second loop-run.

**Solution with paste**

Command `paste` can combine multiple files, and with option `-d` line-by-line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
name=/home/davide/name.txt
number=/home/davide/number.txt

# combine both files linb-by-line
paste $'-d\n' "$name" "$number" |
while read nam
do
    #after reading name to var 'nam', read number to var 'num':
    read num

    # print both
    echo "$nam $num"
done
```

if you want TABS or any other separator and no other processing, you don't need the while loop. Examples

```
paste "$name" "$number"
paste -d: "$name" "$number"
paste -d\| "$name" "$number"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( NR%2 ) {
        tags[++numPairs] = $0
    }
    else {
        vals[numPairs] = $0
    }
    next
}
!(NR%2) {
    for (pairNr=1; pairNr<=numPairs; pairNr++) {
        print prev, tags[pairNr], $0, vals[pairNr]
    }
}
{ prev = $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk number.txt name.txt
*name1 *number1 John 25
*name1 *number2 John 45
*name2 *number1 Paul 25
*name2 *number2 Paul 45
```